# Spring Boot Hystrix : Request is being retried : How to avoid

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

Am building a rest service using spring boot. I am testing the Hystrix timeout configurations in my application; for that I started my server in debug mode and put break point to see how much time it is actually takes to timeout.

While the control comes to break point; I observed that if I let controller to wait for more than the timeout configured; there is yet another same request being spanned somehow.

Is there a way to avoid the second request being spanned?

Comment: What are you using on the client side to generate the request?

Comment: am using chrome plugin postman. I am pretty sure that the client is not making second call. I did verify with other clients as well.

Comment: Are you using hystrix with @HystrixCommand directly? Or using other components like feign or zuul ?

Comment: am using @HystrixCommand  directly.

Comment: Please share some of your code, because Hystrix doesn't have any retry capabilities.